# Running Selenium on Android / Pydroid 3

Tags: python, android, selenium-webdriver, pydroid

I have the following code that works on my mac, but I get an error when I run it on my Android device via Pydroid 3.

It says: "Unable to obtain driver for chrome using selenium manager". I've installed selenium with pips. Is there something I need to do for this to work on my Android device (Google Pixel)?

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(f'https://www.my-path')
```